# How to hide files and folder in windows even if "show hidden files" is on

Tags: windows, file, hide

I want to know how i can hide files even if in explorer the option "show hidden files" is turned on.
but still accessable for programs. a perfect example is the AUTOEXEC.BAT in DOS. it dosen´t show even with "show hidden files" enabled in explorer, but you can see it on cmd. so how can i hide my regular files like this? or does it only work for those files (AUTOEXEC.BAT, CONFIG.SYS, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set both the hidden and system attributes on the file.  From the command line:

```
 attrib +h +s foo.txt
```

To do this in code, use the [SetFileAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfileattributesw) API. Ala:

```
DWORD dwAttrib = GetFileAttributesW(L"foo.txt");
if (dwAttrib != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES)
{
    dwAttrib = dwAttrib | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM;
    SetFileAttributesW(L"foo.txt", dwAttrib);
}
```

Note. This hides the file, but a determined hacker could still see the file by typing "attrib" at the command line with no arguments.